# Styles created using JavaScript are not applied until page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a script that adds the scrollTop value to the height of a DIV

```
var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log(scroll);

        function scrollH() {
            document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = scroll + 'px';
        }

        document.getElementById("overlay").addEventListener("scroll", scrollH());
```

I need this style to keep updating (I'm making a progress bar). Currently it only changes when I refresh the page.

Thanks in advance
(Sorry if I did not follow the correct question format for this site, this is my first question :L )

Comment: When do you call `scrollH`?

Comment: Not really enough code/info here to help. Where's `scroll` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to apply styles via JavaScript after the DOM has loaded.
JQuery helps with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //do something to css
});
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score -1):

You could apply a listener to whatever event is triggering an update, and then replace or fill the progressbar with it's new value.